# python jumble solver algorithm

Tags: python

I need to write  a code for the given problem.

I'm provided with a word and I need to find all the possible combination of it that matches with a given list of words in a file.

Here's my code. Can I make it much better. I'm sure it can be. Please suggest.

```
dict = {}                                                
file = open("/usr/share/dict/words", "r")                

for word in file:                                        #Iterate through every word in the dictionary
        word = word.strip().lower()                        #Strip newlines and send to lowercase
        sorted_word = ''.join(sorted(word))                #Alphabetically sort the word
        if sorted_word in dict:                                #Check if sorted_word is already a key
                if word not in dict[sorted_word]:        #Make sure word is not already in the list under the key sorted_word
                        dict[sorted_word].append(word)        #Add to list under the key sorted_word
        else:                                                #If not in dictionary
                dict[sorted_word] = [word]                #Create new list with one entry
while(True):                                                #Loop until quit is typed
        jumble = raw_input("Enter a jumble to decode or 'quit': ")        #Get input
        jumble = jumble.lower()                                #Send jumble to lower
        if(jumble == "quit"):                                #Quit if quit is typed
                break
        jumble = ''.join(sorted(jumble))                #Sort jumble alphabetical
        if jumble in dict:                                #If sorted jumble exists in dictionary
                results = dict[jumble]                        #Get list of words that match jumble
                for result in results:                        #Loop through list printing results
                        print result,                        #Trailing , designates that there should be a space between entries
                print ""                                #Print newlines
        else:                                                #Jumble not found in dictionary print message
                print "Results for jumble not found"
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because you want a review of working code. It is suitable for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: This is your own personal opinion. I dont want a review. I want a better solution than this. I would've asked for a review in case when it was not working.

Comment: @user1162512 This is certainly a code review type question. Specifically, from the [about](http://stackoverflow.com/about): "Avoid questions that are primarily opinion-based, or that are likely to generate discussion rather than answers." Asking for general suggestions to make the code better does not lend itself to definitive answers.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`set`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set) and [`collections.defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to simplify this some:

```
import collections

# If you try to look up a key that doesn't exist in `words`,
# it will create a new `set()` for that key and return it.
words = collections.defaultdict(set)
with open("/usr/share/dict/words", "r") as file:
    for word in file:
        word = word.strip().lower()
        sorted_word = "".join(sorted(word))
        # `words[sorted_word]` is a set, so there's no need to check if
        # `word` is already in it.
        words[sorted_word].add(word)
```